# How do you stop a properties class from outputting to a file in a illogical order. Workaround?

Tags: java, configuration

I am trying to generate a properties file for a mod I'm making for Minecraft.

The mod will rely a lot of this properties file. It should look something like this:

```
#Comment
#More Comment
#Even more comment explaining.

Button1=Button1   #The data after the equals they would change
Button1Command=/help
Button2=Button2
Button2Command=/rules
```

This would repeat for over 30 button. Here is a test code I used to generate 19 of these options in the config:

```
    Properties p = new Properties();

    try {
        File configDir = new File(Minecraft.getMinecraftDir(), "/config/");
        File config = new File(configDir, "FogHelperConfig.cfg");
        // set the properties value
        for(int c = 18;c >= 0;c--)
        {
        p.setProperty("Button"+c, "Button"+c);
        }
        // save properties minecraft config folder.
        p.store(new FileOutputStream(config), null);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output for this

```
Button18=Button18
Button17=Button17
Button9=Button9
Button16=Button16
Button8=Button8
Button15=Button15
Button7=Button7
Button14=Button14
Button6=Button6
Button13=Button13
Button5=Button5
Button12=Button12
Button4=Button4
Button11=Button11
Button3=Button3
Button10=Button10
Button2=Button2
Button1=Button1
Button0=Button0
```

Of course this is a major problem when I'm dealing with something needs to be in a logical order because it has numbering. I can see this being okay if there were no numbers but in this case it MUST be in order.

I'm assuming there is something I can do or some kind of workaround to fix this issue that the Java Properties class has. I'm willing to have a properties file that I would handmake and package with the mod and just have it placed in a specific location, though I'd prefer to have it generated as it's more user friendly.

Also another thing I would need to do is add comments to this prop file though I'm not quite sure how to.

Any different ways to do this are welcome! Whatever works!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Properties are inherently unordered. [Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/howto_properties.html#Layout_Objects) has some support for handling comments and structure. It might just be easier to post-process the file by sorting, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton As long as whatever way I uses accomplishes my task I don't mind doing different ways. Post-Processing would be fine just my knowledge of Java is not the best so I may have some trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i used the code below to good effect. the natural sort order was good enough for me. you might have to name you buttons like "Button01".

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.*;
public class SortedProperties extends Properties {
    @Override public Set<Object> keySet() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(new TreeSet<Object>(super.keySet()));
    }
    @Override public synchronized Enumeration<Object> keys() {
        return Collections.enumeration(new TreeSet<Object>(super.keySet()));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new SortedProperties() {
            {
                for (int c = 18; c >= 0; c--) {
                    String name = "Button" + (c < 10 ? "0" : "") + c;
                    put(name, name);
                }
            }
        };
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        properties.store(stringWriter, "foo");
        System.err.println(stringWriter.toString());
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand how this code works and therefore do not know how I should implement this and use it based on the code I currently have posted.

Comment: @Fogest You'd use `SortedProperties` instead of `Properties`.

Comment: @DaveNewton do I need to extend it or can I just create the SortedProperties Object instead of the Properties object?

Comment: see edits - sorry about the formating - the {}'s seems to have disapeared.

Comment: this seems to be broken in later versions of java. the keyset is in order but the results of store is not as he is doing a: for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> e : entrySet())

Answer (score 0):

You face two problems. First, the `Properties` class is a subclass of `HashTable`, which is why the entries in it are unsorted. Second, comments are not stored in a `Properties` object.

A better approach is to realise that a properties file is just a text file, you can can open a file, print text to it, and finally close the file. This will give you the flexibility you need: you can use print statements to put comments at the top of the file, and then use a for-loop or while-loop to print *name=value* pairs for however many properties you want the file to contain.